# Polymorphism with smart pointer

Tags: c++, class, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

As the answers pointed out, this is a dumb mistake I made that has nothing to do with polymorphism or smart pointer. The corrected version is in the accepted answer.

============== **Original question** ==================

I am trying to make smart pointer work with polymorphism. In the following prototype code, the implementation for pure `virtual` function `Base::print()` should be in the memory block of `Derived` object. `DerivedWrap` have access to the pointer to the `Derived` object.

Why can not `DerivedWrap::print()` access the function implementation?

```
using namespace std;

class Base 
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
public:
    Derived(int in) : i(in) {}

    void print() {
        cout << "int is " << i << endl;
    }

private:
    int i;
};

class DerivedWrap 
{
public:
    DerivedWrap() : DerivedWrap(make_unique<Derived>(2)) {}
    DerivedWrap(unique_ptr<Base> pBase) : _pBase(move(pBase)) {}

    void print()
    {
        _pBase->print();
    }

private:
    unique_ptr<Base> _pBase;
};

int main() 
{
    DerivedWrap pDW1();
    pDW1->print(); // error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘pDW1’, which is of non-class type ‘DerivedWrap()’

    DerivedWrap pDW2(make_unique<Derived>(2));
    pDW2->print(); // error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘DerivedWrap’
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

- This `DerivedWrap pDW1();` is a function declaration whose return
  type is `DerivedWrap`. It is not calling its default constructor which you are expecting to. You need simply

  ```
  DerivedWrap pDW1;  // calls the default constructor
  // or 
  // DerivedWrap pDW1{};
  ```
- Secondly, the `pDW1` is simply a `DerivedWrap` object. Therefore, no need for calling `operator->`.
  You need in short

  ```
  DerivedWrap pDW1;
  pDW1.print();
  ```

  The same applies to the `pDW2`. You need

  ```
  DerivedWrap pDW2(std::make_unique<Derived>(2));
  pDW2.print();
  ```
- Last but not the least, the `Base` must-have `virtual` destructor for the defined behaviour. See more:
  [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

In short, you need

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
   virtual void print() = 0;
   virtual ~Base() = default;  // provide virtual destructor
};

class Derived /*final*/: public Base
{
public:
   // ... other code

   void print() override // recommended to override the virtual functions
   {
      std::cout << "int is " << i << std::endl;
   }
private:
   int i;
};

class DerivedWrap /* final */
{
public:
   // ...other code

   void print()
   {
      _pBase->print();
   }

private:
   std::unique_ptr<Base> _pBase;
};

int main()
{
   DerivedWrap pDW1; // or DerivedWrap pDW1{};
   pDW1.print();

   DerivedWrap pDW2{ std::make_unique<Derived>(2) };
   pDW2.print();
}
```

---

As a side note, please [do not practice with `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

You have some typos there, it should be:

```
int main()
{
  DerivedWrap pDW1; // object instantiation, no () needed
  pDW1.print(); //no dereferencing required

  DerivedWrap pDW2(make_unique<Derived>(2));
  pDW2.print(); // again, no dereference required

  return 0;
}
```

One other note, for polymorphic objects you're going to need a virtual destructor in your base class.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with polymorphism, virtual functions or smart pointers.

You just made two little typographical mistakes:

1. `DerivedWrap pDW1();` declares a *function*. Remove the `()`.
2. `->` dereferences pointers, but neither `pDW1` nor `pDW2` is a function. Use `.` instead.